# How to make CSS grid that stretches children and respects min-height: 0 on them?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have simple css grid. I'd like it to stretch children to fill available content but also respect it if any of the children has `height: 0`. Right now it also "reserves" space for the child with `height: 0`.
Here's the fiddle showing my problem: 
https://jsfiddle.net/f3r0b5e9/7/

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  align-content: stretch;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #cad5e8;
}

.child.one {
  height: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child one">
  </div>
  <div class="child two">
  </div>
  <div class="child three">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://prntscr.com/kqcry4

Note: I know how to do this with flexbox:)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `auto`, use `min-content` or `max-content` for the `grid-template-rows`'s *value*:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  align-content: stretch;
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #cad5e8;
}

.child.one {
  height: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child one">
  </div>
  <div class="child two">
  </div>
  <div class="child three">
  </div>
</div>
```